# How can the same IOS app communicate with itself?

Tags: ios, sqlite, firebase-realtime-database

I don't think I phrased my question very well but essentially I'm designing an interactive social app and when a post (or something else) is made I want the database to update and for this change to reflect amongst all versions of the app on all devices. By all versions I mean everyone that has this app should be able to refresh the page and view the change (without updating their app from the app store).

I've been researching SQLite as a database and because it's serverless I'm just a little confused as to whether or not that will handle this functionality.

If a user updates the sqlite data base from their version of app, will the changes be updated for everyone?